# Pre-Populate a Multi Select Listbox in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Why doesn't this code open the form with the items selected already?  I set the selection flag to true with this code.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim i, InStrRes, k
With ActiveCell
    If .Value <> "" Then
        For i = 0 To Me.lstDV.ListCount - 1
            InStrRes = InStr(1, ActiveCell.Value, Me.lstDV.List(i))
            If InStrRes <> 0 And InStrRes <> Null Then
                Me.lstDV.Selected(i) = True
            End If
        Next i
    End If
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim i, InStrRes, k
With ActiveCell
    If .Value <> "" Then
        For i = 0 To Me.lstDV.ListCount - 1
            Me.lstDV.Selected(i) = False '<~~ add this code. Should be set to false in advance.
            InStrRes = InStr(1, ActiveCell.Value, Me.lstDV.List(i))
            'If InStrRes <> 0 And InStrRes <> Null Then
            If InStrRes  Then
                Me.lstDV.Selected(i) = True
            End If
        Next i
    End If
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: That doesn't make sense that setting false would make it take true later.  It didn't work.

Comment: @user823527, Uploading your data and user form as images will help us understand your problems.

Answer (score 0):

The presumption must be that the listbox hasn't been loaded at the time it is initialized. I tried the Activate event with similar lack of success. Please try this code instead.

```
Sub ShowMyForm()

    Dim MyForm As New TryForm
    Dim CellVal As Variant

    CellVal = ActiveCell.Value
    With MyForm
        If Len(CellVal) Then
            On Error Resume Next
            .lstDV.ListIndex = Application.Match(CellVal, Range(.lstDV.RowSource), 0) - 1
        End If
        .Show
        ' code continues here when the form is closed
    End With
    Unload MyForm
End Sub
```

This code must be in a standard code module, not the form's code sheet. It calls the form `TryForm` (replace with the name you gave to your form), and modifies it before showing. Note that you still have full access to the form to take out values you may want after it is hidden. Just avoid `Unload Me` anywhere in the form's code because the unloading is done by the above code after you have taken everything you wanted.

Note that the form's Initialize event is triggered by the `New` key word in `Dim MyForm As New TryForm`, long before you gain access. The Activate event follows with some delay. Please make sure that the procedures you may run with these events don't interfere with what the above code does.

Comment: I've made several small edits to both the code and the text of my reply. Please be sure to use the latest version. Thank you.